# Source file having a column in general format, after saving to csv, it appears like 3.81007E+11

Tags: excel, csv, sql-server-2012

Source file having a column in general format, after saving to csv, it appears like 3.81007E+11. Plus, when loading into SQL Server 2012, it stays as `3.81007E+11` which damages the integrity of data

source sample

```
000000000381006794505
000000000002030347199
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't want Excel to touch your numbers, mark the column as `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Open in Excel, format the column as number (without decimals) and save as csv.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Excel.

Excel will convert the representation to scientific notation by default (losing precision along the way).

There are at least two work-arounds

- Format the column as a Number rather than with General formatting.  If this is an integer, set the number of decimal points to 0. To do this, right-click the column header (e.g. "A") to select the whole column, select Format Cells, Click on Number, change Decimal places to 0, click OK.
- Use a leading apostrophe in the value, to inform Excel that this is a string literal, e.g. '000000000381006794505